# Accessing a public member function from a child window's function

Tags: c++, qt

I need to call a parent public member function (`myFunction()`) from a child dialog function (`doStuff()`).  The code below more or less does what I need it to do, but I'm running into some issues.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "myapp.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  myApp app;  // my main app window
  app.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

**myapp.h**

```
...

class MyApp : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MyApp(QWidget* parent = 0);
  void myFunction();

...
```

**myapp.cpp**

```
...

MyApp::MyApp(QWidget* parent)
  : QMainWindow(parent)
  {
    // constructor
  }

MyApp::void myFunction() { 
// do some stuff 
}
```

**mydialog.h**

```
...

class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MyDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
  ~MyDialog();

private:
  void doStuff();

  ...
```

**mydialog.cpp**

```
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget* parent) :
  QDialog(parent, QDialog().windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint)

{
  //constructor
}

void doStuff() {
  ((MyApp*)(parent()))->myFunction(); // this crashes the application
}
```

Ideally, what I would want to do instead of that cast (`((MyApp*)(parent()))->myFunction();`) is something like `app->myFunction()` since I have already created the `MyApp app` instance in `main.cpp`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Show your code for constructing MyDialog object.

Comment: Why you dont use signal and slots?

Comment: You have to store the pointer to the parent window in the child's instance. Otherwise the pointer is not accessible beyond the child's constructor.

Comment: @cantordust: Thanks. How do I do that?

Comment: Put a `MyApp* parent` data member in your `MyDialog` class and assign `parent` to it in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, @CherkesgillerTural. I looked into using signals and slots and solved it. I have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using signals and slots to solve this per Cherkesgiller Tural's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317709/accessing-a-public-member-function-from-a-child-windows-function?noredirect=1#comment81586586_47317709). Here is what I did:

In `mydialog.h`, I added the signal I wanted to emit:

```
signals:
  void sendMySignal();
```

In `mydialog.cpp`, I had the `doStuff()` function emit my signal:

```
void doStuff() {
  emit sendMySignal();
}
```

In `myapp.h`, I added `myFunction` as a public slot and also created an instance of the myDialog:

```
public slots:
  void myFunction();

....

private:
  MyDialog myDialog;
```

In `myapp.cpp`, I added the `connect` line to the constructor:

```
connect(&myDialog, SIGNAL(sendMySignal()), this, SLOT(myFunction()));
```

This `connect` listens for the `sendMySignal()` signal within the `myDialog` object. When the signal is emitted and it is received by `myApp app` (myapp.cpp), it runs the `myFunction()` function, just as I wanted.

Thank you all for the help.